# NestJS ServeStaticModule. Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ServeStaticModule

Tags: nestjs

Couldn't find an answer anywhere for this error. I acted strictly according to the documentation. https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static
I installed the package

```
npm install --save @nestjs/serve-static
```

Next, I include the following code in my file:

`ServeStaticModule.forRoot({rootPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static')}),`

But I am getting this error:

eRROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ServeStaticModule (SERVE_STATIC_MODULE_OPTIONS, AbstractLoader, ?). Please make sure that the argument HttpAdapterHost at index [2] is available in the ServeStaticModule context.

Potential Solutions:

- If HttpAdapterHost is a provider, is it part of the current ServeStaticModule?
- If HttpAdapterHost is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ServeStaticModule?

  @Module({
  imports: [ /* the Module containing HttpAdapterHost */ ]
  })

Comment: this is likely because you, somehow, end up having two nodejs modules loaded of the same package (`@nestjs/core` or `@nestjs/common`, not sure which one could lead to that).

Comment: HttpAdapterHost is provided by ``@nestjs/core``.
So check your dependencies for that package pls. Do the versions match, is the correct version installed etc...

Comment: this is dump, but it may help someone

I encountered this issue, and the source for was that I installed the package in another location
my file structure was as follow root/backend

I installed the package at the root